# Android App is crashing While someone disconnect the opentok call from other devices

Tags: ionic4, cordova-plugins, opentok

Below is my crash log

[App Crashes Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhoSL.png)
Looks like OpenTok Android Plugin.Java is giving exception

```
Exception ->
```

2022-02-11 12:42:06.699 5702-5836/com.guardian.patientconnect I/OTPlugin: session dropped stream

beginning of crash

2022-02-11 12:42:06.754 5702-5836/com.guardian.patientconnect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaBridge
Process: com.guardian.patientconnect, PID: 5702
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8798)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1606)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:5463)
at com.tokbox.cordova.OpenTokAndroidPlugin$RunnableSubscriber.removeStreamView(OpenTokAndroidPlugin.java:375)
at com.tokbox.cordova.OpenTokAndroidPlugin.onStreamDropped(OpenTokAndroidPlugin.java:792)
at com.opentok.android.Session.b(Unknown Source:4)
at com.opentok.android.Session.lambda$XcZSOYrJMUjKBTVPTxPnP7btNyY(Unknown Source:0)
at com.opentok.android.-$$Lambda$Session$XcZSOYrJMUjKBTVPTxPnP7btNyY.run(Unknown Source:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2022-02-11 12:42:06.838 532-1916/system_process W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.guardian.patientconnect/.MainActivity
2022-02-11 12:42:06.841 532-567/system_process W/Looper: Drained

```
public void onStreamDropped(Session arg0, Stream arg1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "session dropped stream");
    streamCollection.remove(arg1.getStreamId());

    streamHasAudio.remove(arg1.getStreamId());
    streamHasVideo.remove(arg1.getStreamId());
    streamVideoDimensions.remove(arg1.getStreamId());

    RunnableSubscriber subscriber = subscriberCollection.get(arg1.getStreamId());
    if (subscriber != null) {
        subscriber.removeStreamView();
        subscriberCollection.remove(arg1.getStreamId());
    }
    triggerStreamEvent(arg1, "sessionEvents", "streamDestroyed");
}
```

can you tell me what is the right approach

Comment: Which version of opentok are you using? and is it the web SDK or android SDK?

Comment: Version ----> cordova-plugin-opentok - 3.4.3 ---> @opentok/client - 2.19.0 and tried with latest version 2.21.7 ---> com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.19.0 and tried with latest version 2.21.5

Comment: are you writing in java/kotlin? seems like there is something being done on the wrong thread and you will need to use `runOnUiThread`

Comment: -> cordova plugin used to give all Java related files for opentok but still I debugged I tried to find out that the above OpentokAndroidPlugin.java file is giving exception.

Comment: I edited my question and given some more information, Please check the above question

Comment: Hi, I am not too familiar with ionic, so not sure this can be fixed on your side. Not sure when someone could take a look at the plugin. But since ionic is web-based, you can add the Opentok JS SDK directly in your project instead of using the plugin for now.